# How to link bullet libraries(from FindBullet.cmake)?

Tags: c++, cmake, bullet

I'm developing a game, and am trying to use bullet. However, (it seems that) I am having trouble linking the bullet libraries. Edit 2: I have [my code on github](https://github.com/loper12/3DPlatformer)

This is actually my first time using cmake. I have searched through the FindBullet.cmake file, and could find the variable to link libraries(${BULLET_LIBRARIES}), but linking the libraries in the variable didn't do anything.

```
    find_package(Bullet REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(3DPlatformer ${BULLET_LIBRARIES})
```

I expected the my code to compile but instead I got a bunch of, "undefined refrence to" then whatever function from bullet it read.
edit:

```
more undefined references to `btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned long, int)' follow
```

^ thats what I got a bunch of

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And that is the last error.
[Full Error](https://gist.github.com/loper12/0a1451b289fdbc9374804d0ee5ab5116)

Comment: _"I am having trouble linking the bullet libraries."_ Is a very vague problem description. Provide a [mcve] reproducing the actual problem as required here please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In whole, your code snippet (`CMakeLists.txt`) seems to be correct. But since you got the error, it could be a problem in some details. This is why we need to see the **exact error message** for being able to help you with your problem. You are trying to describe that error message, but that description doesn't help. Please, [edit] your question post and add the **exact error message** to it. No needs to paste the whole bunch of errors, but the first error is definitely needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is that one of my if statements was broken.
My if statement:

```
if(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
    find_package(Bullet REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(3DPlatformer ${BULLET_LIBRARIES} -lGL -lGLU)
else(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
    add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/bullet" )
    include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/bullet/src")
endif(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
```

was somehow triggering all the code instead of some of it. commenting the code like this:

```
#if(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
    find_package(Bullet REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(3DPlatformer ${BULLET_LIBRARIES} -lGL -lGLU)
#else(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
#   add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/bullet" )
#   include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/bullet/src")
#endif(USE_SYSTEM_BULLET)
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`libbullet-dev` need to be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libbullet-dev
```